# How do I get all the players from a particular team from this dataset

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-datareader

```
| Name | Team |
| a    |Team A|
| b    |Team A|
| c    |Team B|
| d    |Team C|
| e    |Team C|
```

I simply want to get all the players from a particular team of my choice. Say I want all the details of all the players from Team A. All the rows from Team A for every Team A

Answer (score 0):

Use simple slicing?

```
df[df['Team'].eq('Team A')]
```

or:

```
df.loc[df['Team'].eq('Team A'), 'Name']
```